# Deeper drop shadow for focused windows gone in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, compiz, focus, window-decoration

In 11.04, the window in focus had a deeper drop shadow to make it look like it was closer to the user. This feature seems gone in 11.10.

Was this intentional and will this behavior return?

Comment: This has already been reported as a [bug on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/804328). It still hasn't been resolved yet, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's intentional. Shadow is always 8 px to fix some performance issues; see the [changelog for light-themes version 0.1.8.19](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/0.1.8.19).

No idea if/when that will return.